# How to enable GZIP compression on IIS 6.1 under Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: iis, iis-6

We are trying to follow these steps described here:
https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/502ef631-3695-4616-b268-cbe7cf1351ce.mspx?mfr=true

However, at step 1 "In IIS Manager, double-click the local computer, right-click the Web Sites folder, and then click Properties."

We don't see "Websites", but "Sites" and we don't have any "Properties" option when we right click on Sites.

We are running as Adminsitrators.

We don't have the "Compression" icon in our "Feature View" tab.

We were able to make this work without problems under Windows 7 with IIS 7.5

Comment: Did u find a way to enable that on IIS 6.1 @Stephen?